# How to create a main menu in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, scope, submenu

Okay, so I have a clarification, since the question is a little misleading!--I know how to create a menu, list choices and prompt for input, read the user's input, etc.

The issue that I've run into is purely logical. I need to create a main menu with 3 choices:

-Create an array of student "objects" with associated attributes

-Search the list

-Exit

.

At this point, I have boolean-operated while loops that activate the "sub-menus". The booleans become true or false based on whether or not they want to create the list, search, etc.

(Important to know, I have a class above (Student) that contains all of the attribute for the array, such as name, grade average, etc.) The general layout of my main program is as follows:

```
    while(bMainMenu)
        {
            boolean bList = false;
            boolean bSearch = false;

            [all the code prompting choices]
                -if input is "create" then bList = true;
                -if input is "search" then bSearch = true;
                -if input is "exit" then bMainMenu = false;

            while(bList)
                { 
                    [all the code that creates the array and prompts for student info
                     where the array is as long as the user chooses]
                    bList = false;
                }

            while (bSearch)
                {
                    [all the code for searching the array]
                    bSearch = false;
                }

        }
```

After creating the list, everything else is false, and it re-loops the main menu. This time, the user says, "Search", and it makes the boolean for the search menu true.

The issue I'm having: referencing the array that was just created. I'm trying to figure out WHERE I need to call it. As far as I can tell, the way that I've just done everything makes the array contained only within the "bList loop".

Where would I call the array to make it "visible" to the "bSearch" loop? Or do I need to restructure everything differently?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The array needs to be in a scope so that the necessary blocks can access it.  If it is in a while block then it will only be visible to that block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bMainMenu = true;
List<StudentInfo> students = new ArrayList<StudentInfo>();
while(bMainMenu){

    boolean bList = false;
    boolean bSearch = false;

    [all the code prompting choices]
                -if input is "create" then bList = true;
                -if input is "search" then bSearch = true;
                -if input is "exit" then bMainMenu = false;

    while(bList){
        [all the code that creates the array and prompts for student info
                     where the array is as long as the user chooses]

        // Build this student info object based on user parameters
        StudentInfo studentInfo = new StudentInfo(name, class);

        students.add(studentInfo);
    }

    while(bSearch){
        /*      
        Play with "students" arraylist. It is accessible here and contains all studentinfo details added before.
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all about scope. Similar to how you can access your boolean variables `bList` and `bSearch` anywhere within the main outer loop: `while(bMainMenu)`, you can declare your array of students there similarly:

```
while(bMainMenu) {
   Student[] students;
   boolean bList = false;
   boolean bSearch = false;

   // Remaining code can now access students array as it is in scope
}
```

You then instantiate your array later on, for example: `students = new Student[numberStudents]`.

If you don't know how many students will be created upfront or if it will continue to grow in size, consider `ArrayList<Student>` instead.

Comment: Bloody brilliant. Thanks! I didn't know about declaring an array without instantiating it right then--This changes everything!

I considered doing the ArrayList<Student> thing, but my professor just wants me to do it this way for now, and then we'll do the ArrayList later in the semester.

Comment: Actually, the issue I have with doing it the way you posted is that it requires me to initialize the variable--it isn't initialized until the first while loop, and I'm still having  the same issue with scope. The suggesting Eclipse makes is to say "Student[] students = Null;" but obviously, that is wrong...